# How to convert output to a dict in python?

Tags: python

i am new to Python and running into a bit of an issue. I am fetching a response from an endpoint and returning names and number of documents. Code for that Looks like this:-

```
def getDetails(): 
    req = requests.get("url").json() 
    
    for name in req['collections']:
         collection_size = requests.get("string url" + name + "/select?q=*:*&rows=0").json()["response"]["numFound"] 
         print(name, collection_size)

getDetails()
```

And my Output looks like this:-

```
testing1 105042
testing2 558272707
testing3 1328
testing4 1404321
testing5 2152273
testing6 253621
```

So something like this:-

```
for key, value in getDetails():
                l = tr()
                l += td(key, width="10%")
                l += td(value, width="80%")
```

But what if i want to convert it into some sort of `dict()` so i can loop over this output and get the name and number?

This is a relatively new concept to me so excuse any naive mistakes. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Your output looks like that because you `print()` those values directly. Use the values to set items in a dict and you'll have a dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change function like this

```
def getDetails(): 
    req = requests.get("url").json() 
    myDict = {} # Initialize empty dict
    for name in req['collections']:
         collection_size = requests.get("string url" + name + "/select?q=*:*&rows=0").json()["response"]["numFound"] 
         myDict[name] = collection_size # add keys as name and value as collection_size, dynamically 
    
    return myDict
```

And then use it like:

```
myDetails = getDetails()
```

And myDetails is the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Its a pretty simple modification

```
file_dict = dict()
for name in req['collections']:
         collection_size = requests.get("string url" + name + "/select?q=*:*&rows=0").json()["response"]["numFound"] 
         print(name, collection_size)
         file_dict[name] = collection_size
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_